# For two modules over a Hopf algebra $H$, are the module homomorphisms the same as the $H$-invariant linear maps?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra over a field $k$ and $V, W$ two $H$-modules. The antipode and comultiplication on $H$ allow us to turn $\mathrm{Hom}_k(V, W)$ into a $H$-module by setting
$$
(h \cdot f)(v) = h_{(1)}f( S(h_{(2)}) v )
$$
for $h \in H$, $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_k(V, W)$ and $v \in V$. Here $S: H \to H$ denotes the antipode and I am using (sumless) Sweedler notation.

For any $H$-module $V$ we can also define the module of $H$-invariant elements $V^H$ in $V$ as those $v \in V$ satisfying $h \cdot v = \varepsilon(v)$ where $\varepsilon$ denotes the counit of $H$. Now I'm wondering whether
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_H(V, W) = \mathrm{Hom}_k(V, W)^H \,?
$$
More explicitly: For $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_k(V, W)$, is
$$
f(a v) = a f(v) \quad \forall a \in H, v \in V \tag{1}
$$
equivalent to
$$
a_{(1)} f(S(a_{(2)}) v) = \varepsilon(a) f(v) \quad \forall a \in H, v \in V \,? \tag{2}
$$

It's easy to see that (1) implies (2), and I've managed to show that (2) implies (1) when $a = S(b)$ for some $b$, which shows it for all commutative or cocommutative $H$.

Comment: See Lemma 4.1 in Hans-Jürgen Schneider, *Lectures on Hopf algebras*, notes by Sonia Natale ( https://web.archive.org/web/20170809133214/http://www.famaf.unc.edu.ar/series/pdf/pdfBMat/BMat31.pdf ). Note that not all conditions made there are necessary.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Right now it seems to me as if no of the additional assumptions made there are necessary?

Comment: Just for reference the computation in Schneider's notes is $$ f(a v) = \varepsilon(a_{(1)}) f(a_{(2)} v) = (a_{(1)} \cdot f) (a_{(2)} v) = a_{(1)} f(S(a_{(2)}) a_{(3)} v) = a_{(1)} f(\varepsilon(a_{(2)}) v) = a f(v) $$

Comment: Yes, you're right; I was making an unnecessarily weak statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true that $\mathrm{Hom}_H(V, W) = \mathrm{Hom}_(V, W)^H$, without any further assumptions on $H$.

If $f \colon V \to W$ is $H$-linear, then
$$
  (h ⋅ f)(v)
  =
  h^{(1)} f( S(h^{(2)}) v)
  =
  h^{(1)} S(h^{(2)}) f(v)
  =
  ε(h) f(v)
$$
for every element $v$ of $V$, and therefore $h ⋅ f = ε(h) f$.
This means that $f$ is $H$-invariant.

Suppose conversely that $f$ is $H$-invariant.
Then
\begin{align*}
  f(h v)
  &=
  f( ε(h_{(1)}) h_{(2)} v ) \\[0.3em]
  &=
  ε(h_{(1)}) f( h_{(2)} v ) \\[0.3em]
  &=
  (h_{(1)} ⋅ f)( h_{(2)} v ) \\[0.3em]
  &=
  h_{(1)} f( S(h_{(2)}) h_{(3)} v ) \\[0.3em]
  &=
  h_{(1)} f( ε(h_{(2)}) v ) \\[0.3em]
  &=
  h_{(1)} ε(h_{(2)}) f(v) \\[0.3em]
  &=
  h f(v) \,.
\end{align*}

This shows that $f$ is $H$-invariant.